# Removing index numbers in QTablewidget

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

How can I remove the column with index numbers in `QTableWidget` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Not quite obvious, there are two views the vertical and the horizontal header, they are defined in `QTableView`, as any widget you can hide them so its

```
myTableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
```

Comment: My horizontal header is sometimes 4 and some times 5.
Here i am getting some space if it is 4. How to set with out getting blank space

Comment: I don't quite understand the questions but you can set the size of a section through the interface in QHeaderView::resizeSection(int section, int size), see docs for QHeaderView

Answer (score 4):

```
PyQt6
self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
```