# how to combine 2 different stylesheet in QT

Tags: c++, qt

In my application im having a table widget , by using stylesheet i tried to change header border and cells background colors.refer my code below,

```
//to set cell background color as white
tableWidget->setStyleSheet(" QTableWidget::item { border: 1px solid white; }" );
//to set header background as white
tableWidget->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section{background-color: black;color:white;border: 1px solid white;}");
```

now i want to combine both in style sheet. Guide me how to combine above two stylesheets into 1 stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//to set cell background color as white
QString styleSheet = " QTableWidget::item { border: 1px solid white; }";
//to set header background as white
styleSheet += "QHeaderView::section{background-color: black;color:white;border: 1px solid white;}";
tableWidget->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
```

However, you can just put everything in a single line, there is no need to split your stylesheet into two parts like this.

Comment: fantastic its working fine , in my table at left side serial numbers are showing for every row like 1 2 3  4 . How to hide that , guide me to solve this issue also

Comment: @sivanesan, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942951/how-to-remove-index-number-from-qtablewidget

Comment: thank u very much , i ll accept your answer in another 5 min